# jQuery - cant get scrollbars to show in Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

I have some inline content popping up in colorbox but on smaller screens some of it gets lost. I set the 'scroll' option to true in the colorbox script file, but it still doesnt want to work.  anything else i should do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for `overflow:hidden` in the CSS stylesheets or in the script files and if you find it, remove it.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to translate this syntax to `rails`? I'm using `colorbox-rails` and couldn't get the scrollbar to show.

Answer (score 0):

if your colorbox id is like 'colorbx' then
put a jquery like

```
if($('#colorbx').parent().width()<200)
{
    $('#colorbx').css('overflow','scroll');
}
else
{
   $('#colorbx').css('overflow','hidden');
}
```